# Result "10.00" not showing in Mysql query TOP results from 1 to 10

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following query to display a TOP 10 of today's best scores achieved by users.

```
$query = 'SELECT * 
          FROM results 
          WHERE date ="'.$today.'" 
          ORDER BY `score` DESC 
          LIMIT 0 , 10';
```

- the scores are from 1 to 10, and they have the format:  9.20,  9.00 , 8.10, 8.00  etc.
- the highest possible score is 10.00, but it is the only score that isn't displayed in the TOP 10 list.
- I am having a hunch it is seen as 1..something instead of 10, but I am not shure how to debug it. please help

Comment: Show us the description of your table with the `desc TABLENAME` command.

Comment: Can you include a describe of your `results` table and possibly some sample data?  Without that there's nothing we can do but guess at the problem.

Comment: `LIMIT n` means `n` total rows of output, and nothing to do with `score` column. If you want to limit score, use `WHERE score <= 10`

Comment: you probably have more than 10 rows where the score is `<=10`

Comment: Take a look at your `score` column.  What type is it?

Comment: @andrew there are hundreds of rows, but I just want to show 10 of them, the ones with the biggest values in the `score` row

Comment: suppose you have scores `1.1,1.2,4,5,6,7,8.5,9.1,9.5` that's you 10 rows right there `10` will never show because of `limit 0,10`

Comment: @andrew if correct sorted the `10s` should be the 1th to nth result row.

Comment: @andrew: Except that with `order by score desc`, the highest scores will show first.

Comment: @cHao oh i missed the `desc` sorry guys :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that your `score` column is a varchar type and not decimal type. When you use order by on a varchar column, it will sort with the char value and not the integer value. The string '10.00' is lower than '9.90'.

Make sure your database stores scores as decimal instead of varchar.

Comment: is there a way that after I have changed it from varchar to decimal as suggeted, that I could change back and get all my results back as they were?    The results that were 9.80  are now 9   because it wasnt a comma, but it was a dot that separated the number from decimals.

Comment: @KlaussGekker The type you should use is DECIMAL(4,2). Mysql should be smart enough to convert with the good value. Otherwise, you will need to program a script that does the convertion.

Comment: thanks. I have set it up DECIMAL(4,2) and it works just fine from now on